# Truncate results from SQL to integer value

Tags: mysql, sql, integer, rounding, floor

I have different data values (types), like `10.00` or `2.00`. How can I get only its integer value, so I want to get `10` instead of `10.00` and `2` instead of `2.00`?

Comment: how about the round method of mysql? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you cound try to do this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(your_column, SIGNED INTEGER) AS num
FROM 
  table
ORDER BY 
  num;
```

[Based on MySQL Documentation CONVERT() and CAST():](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html)

CONVERT() provides a way to convert data between different character sets. The syntax is:

```
CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)
```

In MySQL, transcoding names are the same as the corresponding character set names.

[Besides for you also could work ROUND(X), ROUND(X,D):](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

Rounds the argument X to D decimal places. The rounding algorithm depends on the data type of X. D defaults to 0 if not specified. D can be negative to cause D digits left of the decimal point of the value X to become zero.

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(150.000,2), ROUND(150,2);
+------------------+--------------+
| ROUND(150.000,2) | ROUND(150,2) |
+------------------+--------------+
|           150.00 |          150 |
+------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Convert could round the number. This might be undesirable.

Comment: That is true, might be undesirable. Depends on.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`FLOOR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) or [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) function depending on your intention:

```
SELECT FLOOR(1.999)        --  1
SELECT FLOOR(-1.999)       -- -2
SELECT TRUNCATE(1.999, 0)  --  1
SELECT TRUNCATE(-1.999, 0) -- -1
```

Comment: Your example, could also serve for his/her purpose! +1